# XCode>Instruments>Leaks - Where is "gather leaked memory contents" data?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, instruments, memory-leaks

When you check **gather leaked memory contents** in the **Leaks** instrument what does this do? I have a troublesome leak and thought maybe this "memory content" might be useful in tracking it down...but I can't find it!?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The data ends up at the bottom of the stack trace in the "Extended Detail" sidebar.  Un-disclose the triangle in the stack header to make it more obvious, like in the screenshot below.

[image: Instruments screen shot]